# Can't delete a dynamic selection field in JS

Tags: javascript, function, object, multipleselection

I'm having troubles to delete dynamically created object selection fields. I've tried several things to delete the fields including putting the objects inside an array as they are created and then trying to pop them away. Basically what I want to do is to be able to add selection fields as needed and remove them 1 by 1 with a cross button beside the selection field.

The code is not mine and I'm just starting with JS, HTML and CSS. I'm more of a python guy.

So can anybody help me to get it done please? I'm doing this for a company so failing is a big No-No

Attached are the photos of the code and what the result is:

Greetings
El_Capit4n

PS.: don#t bother with the flow_variables errors... I disabled them in the code in order to make it run.

Here at the beginning is the declaration of the dynamic field creation:

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlvUn.png)
[Its output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K2RA.png)

Note that its only a part of the program

Whole JS/HTML/CSS Code:

```js
// Global vars
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var feature_options = ["MIN","MAX","MEAN"];
var operator_options = [">","<","=",">=","<=","LIKE"];


var i;
const arrayselection = [];
var x;
var criterium_num=1;
var criteria_count=0;
var first_key_flag=true;

/* ********** HTML ********** */
html ='<h1> Filterentwurf </h1>';
html+='<p id="debug">Debug</p>';
html += '<form id="criteria_form" autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php"></form>';
html += '<br><button class="buttons" id="delete"> X </button><br>';
html += '<br><button class="buttons" id="btn"> <b>+</b> Neues Kriterium hinzufügen</button><br>';

filter_conf=    //'<form  action="/action_page.php" class="filter_conf" id="filter_class">'+
                '<p>Filter Einstellung:</p>'+
          '<input type="radio" id="no_filt" name="filter_conf" value="4">'+
                '<label for="no_filt">Keine Signale auswählen</label><br>'+
                '<input type="radio" id="filt_conjunction" name="filter_conf" value="1">'+
                '<label for="filt_conjunction">Alle Kriterien erfüllen</label><br>'+
                '<input type="radio" id="filt_disjunction" name="filter_conf" value="2">'+
                '<label for="filt_disjunction">Mindestens ein Kriterium erfüllen</label><br>'+
                '<input type="radio" id="filt_advanced" name="filter_conf" value="3">'+
                '<label for="filt_advanced">Manuele Eingabe der Filtereinstellung</label><br>',
          
            //'</form>';
html +=filter_conf;
html +=  '<input type="text" id="filter_def" style="display:none">';


body.innerHTML=html;


/* **********  JavaScript  **********   */

// Add new criteria by clucking on button 
document.querySelector("#btn").onclick = function add_signal(event) {
    x= create_filter_criterium(criterium_num);
  arrayselection.push(x)
    criterium_num+=1;
}


 document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function(event) {
    const index = arrayselection.indexOf(criterium_num);
  arrayselection.splice(index, 1);
  criterium_num-= 1;
  
  
 
  
}

// Add function to hide and show ComplexQuery
document.querySelector("#filt_advanced").onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("filter_def").style.display="block"
    FLOW_VARIABLES["filter_def"]="filt_advanced";
}

document.querySelector("#no_filt").onclick = function(event){
  document.getElementById("filter_def").style.display="none"
    document.getElementById("filter_def").value=""
  FLOW_VARIABLES["filter_def"]="No_Signal";
}

document.querySelector("#filt_conjunction").onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("filter_def").style.display="none"
    document.getElementById("filter_def").value=""
    FLOW_VARIABLES["filter_def"]="conjunction";
}

document.querySelector("#filt_disjunction").onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("filter_def").style.display="none"
    document.getElementById("filter_def").value=""
    FLOW_VARIABLES["filter_def"]="disjunction";
}



// inititialize input field for first criterium
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      // somehow not working ...
     document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "doc loaded";
    create_filter_criterium(1);
    criterium_num+=1;
  });
document.addEventListener("onmousemove", function(event) {
      // substitute of document.addEventListener("load", function(event) ... somehow not working
      //event activated after first keypressed
     if (first_key_flag=true){
         document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "doc loaded";
        create_filter_criterium(1);
        criterium_num+=1;
        }
     first_key_flag=false;      
  });

// create new criterium
function create_filter_criterium(criterium_num){
    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "Button Presed";

    criteria=document.getElementById("criteria_form");
    //Signal
    signal_input=document.createElement("input");
    signal_input.id = "signal"+criterium_num.toString();
    signal_input.type = "text";
    signal_input.placeholder="Signal "+criterium_num.toString();
    signal_div=document.createElement("div");
    signal_div.className="autocomplete";
    signal_div.style="width:50%";
    signal_div.innerHTML=signal_input.outerHTML;
    // feature
    feature_input=document.createElement("input");
    feature_input.id = "feature"+criterium_num.toString();
    feature_input.type = "text";
    feature_input.placeholder="Merkmal "+criterium_num.toString();
    feature_div=document.createElement("div");
    feature_div.className="autocomplete";
    feature_div.style="width:10%";
    feature_div.innerHTML=feature_input.outerHTML;
    // operator
    operator_input=document.createElement("input");
    operator_input.id = "operator"+criterium_num.toString();
    operator_input.type = "text";
    operator_input.placeholder="Operator "+criterium_num.toString();
    operator_div=document.createElement("div");
    operator_div.className="autocomplete";
    operator_div.style="width:10%";
    operator_div.innerHTML=operator_input.outerHTML;    
    // value
    value_input=document.createElement("input");
    value_input.id = "value"+criterium_num.toString();
    value_input.type = "text";
    value_input.placeholder="Wert "+criterium_num.toString();
    value_div=document.createElement("div");
    value_div.className="autocomplete";
    value_div.style="width:15%";
    value_div.innerHTML=value_input.outerHTML;  
    // index
    index_input=document.createElement("P");
    index_input.id = "index"+criterium_num.toString();
    index_input.innerText = "Q"+criterium_num.toString();
    //index_input.placeholder="Wert "+criterium_num.toString();
    index_div=document.createElement("div");
    index_div.className="autocomplete";
    index_div.style="width:5%";
    index_div.innerHTML=index_input.outerHTML;  
    // white space  
    white_space=document.createElement("P");
    white_space.innerText = "";
    white_space_div=document.createElement("div");
    white_space_div.className="autocomplete";
    white_space_div.style="width:2%";
    white_space_div.innerHTML=white_space.outerHTML;
    ws=white_space_div.outerHTML;
    
    var criterium=document.createElement("div");
    criterium.display="block";
    criterium.innerHTML=index_div.outerHTML+ws+signal_div.outerHTML+ws+feature_div.outerHTML+ws+operator_div.outerHTML+ws+value_div.outerHTML;
    
    criteria.appendChild(criterium);
    criteria_count+=1;
    
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("signal"+criterium_num.toString()), signal_options);
    dropdown(document.getElementById("feature"+criterium_num.toString()), feature_options);
    dropdown(document.getElementById("operator"+criterium_num.toString()), operator_options);
    }

// autocomplete functions
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        //if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        if (arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase())!== -1) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          //b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          //b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML = arr[i].substr(0, arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()));
          b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()), val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length+arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()))
          //b.innerHTML += arr[i]; // not bold display 
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
      x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
    }
  }
}
/*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}

// dropdown functions
function dropdown(inp, arr) {
  /*the dropdown function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      //if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        //if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.innerHTML = arr[i];
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
            inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            /*close the list of autocompleted values,
            (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
            closeAllLists();
            });
        a.appendChild(b);        
      }
      /*close dropdown after moving the pointer out of it*/
    a.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
        closeAllLists();
    });
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
      x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
    }
  }
}
/*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}

// Set Output variables as a ','-concatenated string of the manually selected signals
setInterval(function(){ 
    FLOW_VARIABLES["debug"]=6;
    //document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "Criteria Count: "+criteria_count.toString();
    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "";
    /* actualize input variables every 0.2 seconds*/
    FLOW_VARIABLES["signals"]='';
    FLOW_VARIABLES["features"]=''; 
    FLOW_VARIABLES["operators"]=''; 
    FLOW_VARIABLES["values"]=''; 
    FLOW_VARIABLES["indices"]='';
    
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= criteria_count; i++) {
        FLOW_VARIABLES["signals"]+=document.getElementById("signal"+i.toString()).value;
        FLOW_VARIABLES["features"]+=document.getElementById("feature"+i.toString()).value;
        FLOW_VARIABLES["operators"]+=document.getElementById("operator"+i.toString()).value;
        FLOW_VARIABLES["values"]+=document.getElementById("value"+i.toString()).value;
        FLOW_VARIABLES["indices"]+=document.getElementById("index"+i.toString()).innerText;
        if (i!=criteria_count){
            FLOW_VARIABLES["signals"]+=',';
            FLOW_VARIABLES["features"]+=',';
            FLOW_VARIABLES["operators"]+=',';
            FLOW_VARIABLES["values"]+=',';
            FLOW_VARIABLES["indices"]+=',';
        }
    }
    
    //define filter as user's input
    if (document.getElementById("filt_advanced").value){
        FLOW_VARIABLES["filter_def"]=document.getElementById("filter_def").value;
    }



}, 100);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.success {
    color: #006633;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.background {
    color: #000000;
}

.filter_conf{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 3px 8px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.failure {
    color: #990000;
    font-weight: bold;
}


* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  margin: 3px 8px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=radial] {
  width: 3%;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 21px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use images from the code, put it here as example, so thers can copy it for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fault. You have to increment/decrement criterium_num at the onclick event from the 2 buttons just at beginning. For deleting the criterium you have to search the corresponding div and set it's outerHTML to ''. For preventing to get negativ index of criterium I set it to 1 if it's smaller 1 through multiple click on the delte-button (too much delition).

```
document.querySelector("#btn").onclick = function add_signal(event) {
    if (criterium_num<1) criterium_num=1;
    x = create_filter_criterium(criterium_num++);
    arrayselection.push(x)
}

 document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function(event) {
    const index = arrayselection.indexOf(criterium_num--);
    document.getElementById('criterium_'+criterium_num).outerHTML='';
    arrayselection.splice(index, 1);
}
```

For finding this div you need to add to the criterium an id.

```
var criterium=document.createElement("div");
criterium.display="block";
criterium.id='criterium_'+criterium_num;
criterium.innerHTML=index_div.outerHTML+ws+signal_div.outerHTML+ws+feature_div.outerHTML+ws+operator_div.outerHTML+ws+value_div.outerHTML;
```

For testing you can use https://jsfiddle.net/r2ya49cv/1/ where is the whole code while here only the relevant lines are listed.

Please controll exact that the indexes are correct both on the view  and in the criteria because you are using a production-system.

**Remark:** Please short the next time your code for only the relevant part. It's for others tedious to search the relevant parts and it makes it much more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much Sascha. I'm just beginning with JS and you really helped me !!